# Knockout JS List Selection Extremely Slow

Tags: list, select, knockout.js

I've got a drop down list of 2,000 items.  If I use knockout JS to build this list, things are fine.  When I set the `value` tag in the list, however, the list becomes super slow to respond (3 seconds to update the selected item).

Is this expected?

```
<select id="schoolName" data-bind="options: schools, value: selectedSchool, optionsText: 'CommonName'">
</select>
```

It only happens when I have the `value` tag inserted (which I need, because I need the value of the selected item).

Thanks

Comment: 2,000 items in a select list!!! Something is seriously wrong with the UX...I pity the end user...

Comment: I don't have any experience with auto-complete, so this is iteration one on the design.  Maybe I should look into that (it would at least get rid of the large list)

Comment: Did you check jQuery autocomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2000 items, you definitely want an autocomplete.  There is discussion on how to autocomplete in google groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/knockoutjs/ABhEeI7jLKA).

RPN has a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YNCTY/ that shows an autocomplete custom knockout binding.  I just implemented the ajax version of this today and it works really, really well.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how to implement this in ajax.  Could you post an example or show me to a link that gives me some pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: NVM, saw the link in the Google Group Discussion. Thanks:  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MJQ6g/